# Azure Web Job Not Triggering When Messages are added to the queue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I am attempting to diagnose the root cause of unwanted behavior exhibited by an Azure Web Job I am running.

The Facts:

I have a an Azure Web Job that works most of the time, however every couple of days it just stops processing messages.

CPU and Memory seem fine:
[image]

You can see the last successful run was several hours ago:
[image]

There are several hundred messages still in the queue:

[image]

Having confirmed nothing has been changed as far as configuration or executable in the last 24 hours, what could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I located a message that had caused an infinite loop and was never finishing processing. I had set `jobHostConfiguration.Queues.BatchSize = 1;` So it was never processing additional messages until it completed or failed the current one.

It is strange to me that this was not the most recent message on the Azure Web Jobs Dashboard. But looking on page two I found and stopped the message being processed:

[image]